# Systemd immidiately running execstop

Tags: systemd

At work, we are running Nagios for system monitoring. I have written a python script to store data from Nagios in a postgresql database. This is running on centos 7.6. Using a systemd service file, I have no problem starting the script and having it restarted if it for some reason should go down. I can stop the script in a controlled way by writing a file in a certain location. This works fine to stop it manually, but it does not work if I try to use it through systemd.

My service file is like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Nagiosdata to postgresql
After=postgresql-12.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/nagios/libexec/importdata
StandardInput=null
User=nagios
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30s
TimeoutStopSec= 180 
ExecStop=/usr/bin/touch <file to stop the process>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I add in TimeoutStopSec and ExecStop as shown here, systemd will write out the control file immideately after starting the process so the process will stop again. I have tried to set Type to forking (which as far as I do understand is not correct since my script runs in the foreground if run interactively) but with the same result.

I notice if I do systemctl status dataimport, if I do not have the ExecStop line, status is Active (running). With the ExecStop, I have status Active (exited)

Do I need to do something differently or will this just not work on systemd 219 on centos 7.6?

Comment: a) Is your python script a continuous service (you might want to add `RemainAfterExit=true`)? b) How is the service stop triggered by existence of a file?

Comment: a) Yes b) if os.path.exists(markerfile): <do cleanup> break (out of infinite loop)

Comment: I have read about RemainAfterExit, but as far as I have understood, it plays poorly with auto restart?

Comment: As your service is infinite, `RemainAfterExit` is not relevant (this is for commands that run and then a service should be considered active despite the commands having finished). It seems to me your service is biting it's tail: how could it ever successfully restart once the markerfile exists if even `ExecStop` creates the markerfile?

Comment: The first part of the cleanup is to remove the markerfile. With a service file without the ExecStop, the service runs without any problems, as soon as I add ExecStop, the service terminates immideately.

Comment: Have you checked the log for error messages?

Comment: Good point, but nothing special to be seen there, The normal startup messages and then it is quitting.